# State was undefined for like 0.3s and then got data from API

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load data right away when I click to new page but data have to load 0.3-0.5s to load and my component was getting error because state was undefined.

Here is my following code how I fetch my data from backend:

```
  const [invitees, setInvitees] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [inviteeList, setInviteeList] = useState(invitees);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  const [currentInvitee, setCurrentInvitee] = useState(null);

  const fetchInviteData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/invites/sent/${teamId}`);
    // Set state
    const items = res.data.map((item) => ({
      fullname: item.User.fullname,
      picture:
        item.User.picture ||
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_1280.png",
      role: "invited",
      position: "Frontend Developer",
      email: item.User.Email,
      institution: item.User.institution,
      linkedin: item.User.linkedin,
      location: item.User.location,
      major: item.User.major,
      webpage: item.User.webpage,
      invited: {
        accepted: item.response === "Accepted",
        declined: item.response === "Declined",
        date: "2020-06-13",
      },
      Ratings: item.User.Ratings,
      Skills: item.User.Skills,
    }));
    setInvitees([...items]);
    setInviteeList([...items]);
    setCurrentInvitee(items[0]);
    // Toggle loading state
    setLoading(false);
  };

  // Load invites function
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInviteData();
  }, [teamId]);
```

and I'm getting error at this line of code:

```
  {currentInvitee.invited.accepted && tabs[activeTab] === "Accepted" && (
    <div className="invitee-profile-view">
      {currentInvitee && (
        <MemberCard {...currentInvitee} currentInvitee={currentInvitee} />
      )}
    </div>
  )}
```

> Error: currentInvitee.invited.accepted is undefined

if I comment it out the component will run and `currentInvitee.invited.accepted` will load. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try instead of `currentInvitee.invited.accepted` use `currentInvitee?.invited?.accepted`. Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{typeof currentInvitee !== "undefined" && currentInvitee.invited.accepted &&
  tabs[activeTab] === "Accepted" && (
   <div className="invitee-profile-view">
     {currentInvitee && (
       <MemberCard {...currentInvitee} currentInvitee={currentInvitee} />
     )}
   </div>
 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would try to do is to just load the component on the page once you have finished fetching the data. For such you could create a new state like:

`const [shouldRenderComponent, setShouldRenderComponentTo] = useState(false);`

You should change this state to `true` right after your application has finished loading the data, for this I would add the following line right after `setLoading(false)`:

```
setInvitees([...items]);
    setInviteeList([...items]);
    setCurrentInvitee(items[0]);
    // Toggle loading state
    setLoading(false);
    **setShouldRenderComponentTo(true)**
```

Now you know that your component can be rendered when shouldRenderCompoment is `true`, furthermore, you know that the property `invited` from `currentInvitee` has already been loaded and can be accessed. Then you could do the following:

```
{shouldRenderComponent && currentInvitee.invited.accepted && tabs[activeTab] === "Accepted" && (
    <div className="invitee-profile-view">
      {currentInvitee && (
        <MemberCard {...currentInvitee} currentInvitee={currentInvitee} />
      )}
    </div>
  )}
```

Basicaly, just put `shouldRenderComponent` in front of your boolean statement (or how ever you call this check that says if you should render a component or not).

But Nathan's ideia could be used to supplement this check statement, in order to avoid crashing. This means you could use the following:

```
{shouldRenderComponent && currentInvitee?.invited?.accepted && tabs[activeTab] === "Accepted" && (
    <div className="invitee-profile-view">
      {currentInvitee && (
        <MemberCard {...currentInvitee} currentInvitee={currentInvitee} />
      )}
    </div>
  )}
```